# What artificial life games are available for Ubuntu?

Tags: games

I am something of a fan of [artificial life](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_life) / evolution simulation games. What games of this genre are available for Ubuntu?

Preferably it should be something fairly complex yet user-friendly; note that I'm not talking about [Game of Life](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life) clones (too rigid for my taste).

Comment: I don't know any personally, but a quick search only produced many. https://duckduckgo.com/?q=linux+artificial+life+simulator&t=canonical

Answer (score 3):

Critterding is a 3D physics and neural network alife simulator with a package available for Ubuntu.

Evolve4.0 isn't a linux program but runs happily through wine! (install through winefile)

Answer (score 0):

if you go to Ubuntu Software Center (the little shopping bag icon, or search for "Software" in the dash), you can search by category or keyword.  Categories -> Games -> Simulation turns up a few but the pickings are slim.  Many that are included in the software center are pretty weak but LinCity NG is pretty good.

Here is a list of some others that you can download.  I haven't tried any of them but some look pretty slick.

http://www.lgdb.org/category/genre/simulation

Comment: Hmm...LinCity looks outside of the scope of my search. I'm looking for something a bit more biological in theme.

Answer (score 0):

My favorite is this java program, Biogenesis: http://biogenesis.sourceforge.net

It's a reimplementation of an windows app, called Primordial Life. It's very fun to watch.

The only other lead I found was this list, which looks about 10 years old: http://www.cs.iastate.edu/~baojie/acad/reference/forge/alife.htm

Forgive the lateness of my answer, I only found your question after searching for the same thing myself today.